# PHP - apply ucfirst() to first character that isn't HTML

Tags: php, regex, capitalization, ucfirst

I'm outputting a string assembled from a few different parts, and some of those parts may or may not contain some HTML. If I apply `ucfirst()` to the string and there's HTML before the text to be displayed then the text doesn't get proper capitalization.

```
$output = $before_text . $text . $after_text;
```

So if I've got

```
$before_text = 'this is the lead into ';
$text = 'the rest of the sentence';
$after_text = '.';
```

then `ucfirst()` works fine and `$output` will be

> This is the lead in to the rest of the sentence.

But this

```
$before_text = '<p>';
$text = '<a href="#">the sentence</a>.';
$after_text = '</p>';
```

won't do anything. So I guess I need a function or regex to make its way to the first actual, regular text and then capitalize it. But I can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you considered using css? It's much more easier and efficient that way, IMO.
text-transform: uppercase;

Comment: Is $text always max 1 html tag or it can be more?

Comment: Do you have control over the string of HTML you're assembling, or no? If you do, you should be able to add logic quite easily to ensure your text has `ucfirst()` applied.

Comment: @pnknrg the $before_text, $text, and $after_text can be pretty much anything. Whether or not that's a bad idea is a different discussion.

Comment: @1000Nettles there's no telling what could be in there.

Comment: Please provide more test cases: `what <b>is</b> it?`, `<b>w<i>hat</i> is it?</b>`, etc.

Comment: @SmokingSheriff good idea, so I just tried it. In this particular case the first item is an SVG icon, which apparently counts as ::first-letter.

Comment: For anyone looking for something similar: _do not try parsing HTML with regex_ : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. use strip_tags in $text and save in $temp: this should give you text that is not html.
2. apply ucfirst on $temp and call it $temp_ucfirst: this should give you string upper-cased.
3. use str_replace to replace $temp in $text with $temp_ucfirst: this should replace the not-html text with the upper-cased one.

Comment: That's a winner! Thanks!

Comment: Could include what functions you're using in step #3 for a case-insensitive search and replace but +1 for a creative solution without needing to use DOMDocument.